# Simple Python Class Not Displaying/Printing Anything

Tags: python

I am trying to create this class that would display an Employee's name and his yearly salary. Everything seems to be working and I haven't encountered any errors, but when I run the program, nothing is printed.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        
    def Func(self):    
        print("Employee name is" + self.name)
    
employee1 = Employee("Adam Smith", "$47,000")
print(employee1.salary)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please double-check your indentation. What output are you expecting?

Comment: Is the code indentation correct? Can you please check that?

Comment: The indentation is wrong, consider it fixed there is no problem and output gets printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a indentation error, Use :

```
class Employee:
# Error is here
    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
    
    def Func(self):    
        print("Employee name is" + self.name)

employee1 = Employee("Adam Smith", "$47,000")
print(employee1.salary)
```

Comment: I would guess `Func`, as it defines the `self` parameter, is intended to be a *method*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried running the code, it runs either ways.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have anyway edited the code, please remove the downvote if possible

Comment: What do you mean *"either ways"*? At the moment it's never invoked anyway. And what do you think makes the latter function option better?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I get your point now, I assumed it to be outside the class and ran the code, since it was working, I posted it here.